# Why does fgets return a bad string?

Tags: c, string, printf, fgets

I don't know how else to put it, but I know I'm doing something wrong.

```
char *temp2= "/shares/mJim";
char ourList[1024];

fgets(ourList, 1024, modified)

sprintf(sysString, "grep -c %s %s", ourList, temp2);
```

Now fgets does its job, but when I try to form this string with sprintf I get `grep -c Lanuncher.ini` and the rest is missing. Now here is the kicker, if I reverse the order like this:

```
sprintf(sysString, "grep -c %s %s", temp2, ourList);
```

The result will be what I want, but and invalid search for grep: `grep -c /shares/mJim Lanucher.ini`

Also if I do this:

```
sprintf(sysString, "grep -c %s %s", temp2, temp2);
```

It creates the expected string (`grep -c /shares/mJim /shares/mJim`). Does anyone know what is going on?

Well for input its a simple text file that is a single column list:

```
Launcher.ini
bits.exe
etc....
```

The garbage in this case is the unusually short string that I mentioned. When I print out what ourList has it returns Launcher.ini.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you could show us: (1) sample input, (2) the alleged "garbage".

Comment: Yes the '\n' was the issue thank you for the aid everyone.

Comment: Make sure to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fgets` includes a trailing `'\n'`. You probably want to remove it before building sysString ...

```
fgets(ourList, sizeof ourList, modified);
size_t ourListlen = strlen(ourList);
if (ourListlen && (ourList[ourListlen - 1] == '\n')) {
    ourList[--ourListlen] = 0; /* remove trailing '\n' and update ourListlen */
}
```

Comment: Of course, you should check the return value of `fgets` and deal with any errors in a suitable way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure. Is ourList big enough?  You should also really, really check the return value of fgets().

Comment: +1 for suggesting that the return value of `fgets` be checked :)

Answer (score 1):

If the line you're reading from the `modified` FILE stream contains a newline, that [newline will be included](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) in the returned character string. Chances are, you have:

```
"Launcher.ini\n"
```

Strip the newline, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Ill try that, it might be the issue, in response to all of your suggestions ofc.